# Connect two sheet materials with no access to other side

Tags: construction, materials

I want to make a connection between to thin sheet materials that can be disassambled. Seems easy enough, right? Just use nut bolt and washers. The problem is that when the connection is made there is no hand access to other side to hold the nut. I cannot make a thread too. Is there any better solution that glue the bolt to other side ? Maybe someone has already invented a type of one-side-locking-bolt? The connection does not need be super strong. The this is a lid or cover of some sort, imagine a light car hood.

Comment: Magnets and hook-and-loop tape come to mind. I think you need to de-abstract your description a bit, and demonstrate that it's relevant to home improvement (as opposed to a hobby project).

Comment: How thin are the materials?  I agree with riv-nuts, but they will be questionable in very thin materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oftentimes a **riv-nut** can be used. Similar to a rivet, it is installed from one side and fastened with a special tool. It is internally threaded such that a machine screw or bolt may be used. $22 US for kit including tool and "threaded inserts" at discount tool supplier:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a [t-nut](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Hardware-Fasteners-Nuts-Tee-Nuts/N-5yc1vZc2a4). You drill a hole and then attach the t-nut. The ones for wood get hammered in, but there are also ones for metal which get screwed in.